# Getting an image source with sed

Tags: unix, sed

If I have a line of text which looks like...

```
[garbage] <img src="[some url]" [garbage] /> [garbage]
```

Using sed, how can I get the URL that the image is pointing to? There are no other instances of `src=` on that line.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
cat html | sed -n 's/.*<img src="\([^"]*\)".*/\1/p'
```

The -n /p idiom allows you to ignore all the other lines in the file (i.e. do a sed and a grep in one go), while "([^"]*)" just says find the stuff in the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby (1.9+)

```
$ ruby -ne 'puts $_.scan(/img src=\"(.[^"]*)/)' file
```